# How can I save the order a list of hidden form inputs which represent an array in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list of items which are generated from an array property on a model. I want to use jquery UI sortable to reorder the items and save this order in my Action method.

Here is the code I am using to output the items:

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        @{
            int count = 0;
        }
        @foreach(var item in Model.CollectionOfThings)
        {
            <li class="ui-state-default">
                @Html.Hidden("Things[" + count + "].Id", item.Id)
                @Html.Hidden("Things[" + count + "].Title", item.Title)
                @item.Title
            </li>
            count++;
        }
    </ul>    
}
```

When I receive the model in my action method the order is the same as when I started. I understand that this is because of the index but I can't figure out a way (without writing some custom javascript to update the name attribute of each hidden input) to have the items bound to the array in correct order.

Can anyone suggest a way this could be achieved? I can probably write a bit of Javascript to do it but I hoped I could do this purely with model binding.

I tried outputting the inputs like this:

```
@Html.Hidden("Things[].Id", item.Id)
```

However this just resulted in my collection being null.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered [a blog post from Phil Haack which contained the answer](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

By using arbitrary indexes in a seperate hidden input with the name of my collection + `.Index`, the model binder seems to handle it and maintain the order.

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        @{
            int count = 0;
        }
        @foreach(var item in Model.CollectionOfThings)
        {
            <li class="ui-state-default">
                @Html.Hidden("Things.Index", "item" + count)
                @Html.Hidden("Things[item" + count + "].Id", item.Id)
                @Html.Hidden("Things[item" + count + "].Title", item.Title)
                @item.Title
            </li>
            count++;
        }
    </ul>    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution for you can be to collect only Ids. I assume titles can be recreated on server side. In this case you can just define:

```
@Html.Hidden("ThingIds", item.Id)
```

and bind to

```
List<int> thingsIds
```